# Write LogFile with date on running service

Tags: php, linux, bash, logging, reactphp

I've created a service with reactphp which runs and does some stuff. It is started as a daemon so all output should be logged in a file. 
This log file should be named **'foo-log-file-$(date "+F")'**. I want to have a single log file for each day.

### Problem:

As mentioned the script runs as a service, without stopping. The starting call for the script is therefore only done once.

```
php my_script.php >> /var/log/bar/log-file--$(date "+%F") 2>&1
```

So everything which is printed to the console from this script is saved into the file, but the file is only created with the date-string when it was called and is not updated with a new date.

### Question:

Is it possible to solve this without writing the log logic in the php-script? Can i handle this requirement with bash?

Comment: You can probably run a cronjob for this, to be run every day for example.

Comment: @fedorqui what exactly do you mean with a "cronjob", the start of the daemon is only once, so what should this cronjob exactly do?

Comment: Uhms, I did not understand the issue properly. Now I see: the log file name is generated when you start the application. Then, you want to have this file changed every day. For this, you may want to use [rotate](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/). It will automatically move the log under some circumstances, so that you can "move" one at 00.00 of the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI
The answer of @fedorqui was a good approach, i solved it with a cronjob, which copies the file to a different one and empties the rest. 
You cannot use move, cause the through the running service, it is open all time and you get the error:

```
cannot move 'foo.log' to 'bar.log': Text file busy
```

So i cp it and clear the old one with:

```
cp foo.log foo.log.$(date +"%F");
cp /dev/null file.log;
```

Comment: Nice! Note you can also say `> file` to empty it.